# Calculating bond length in VMD (Visual Molecular Dynamics)

Tags: computational-chemistry

Is there a way to calculate bond length in VMD (Visual Molecular Dynamics)?
I have a lot of trajectory files of water molecule, and I need to calculate the bond length of $\ce{O-H}$ bond, and find the average.

I know that there is a GUI based method to calculate bond lengths in VMD, but can I do the same using a script?

Comment: The answer is "of course". The thing is there are a lot of ways to do this. If you are looking for a "canned" way to do this, you can wait for someone to answer. Otherwise I recommend searching the VMD site including sample scripts. You can also write your own script in your own favorite programming language. If you don't have one it might be a good opportunity to learn one.

Comment: @NightWriter I would love to write my own script, perhaps in Python or Fortran. But I haven't really been able to, because I don't know how to extract data from .dat files efficiently. Do you have resource recommendations for that?

Comment: That sounds like a chicken and egg problem. If you know how to program then writing a program to inspect such a file should not be too difficult. You may want to look at this: https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Training/Tutorials/vmd/tutorial-html/node7.html  I can't elaborate on this at present, but the native VMD TCL scripting language is not necessarily the easiest to wrap you head around, and scripts may not work straight from the webpage (you might have to do some tinkering with the code).

Comment: Also,  what do you mean efficiently? If you hope someone will post an answer here you may want to include more information into the question by editing it. What does your .dat file look like?